# Fetch the image and display it with Authorization in react

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm going to fetch an image from ASP.NET core 5 web API and display it in react (with Authorization)
But I get the following error
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vqVJ.png)

when I remove Authorize and open the photo in the browser, the photo is displayed correctly

This is my code in react :

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

const Test = () => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState();
  useEffect(async () => {
    const API_URL =
      process.env.REACT_APP_URL +
      "/Images/testimg/94e51231-cab8-4c51-8ee5-15b0da3164a4.jpg";
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
        headers: {
          responseType: "arraybuffer",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var buffer = Buffer.from(response.data,"base64")
        setSource(buffer);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(source);

  return (
      <img
        id="test-img"
        src={`data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,${source}`}
      />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

And This is my code in ASP.NET core 5 web API:

```
[Route("testimg/{name}")]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult testimg(string name)
        {
    string curentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(curentPath, $"resources\\{name}");
    var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fullPath);
    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Looks like the value being returned from API is coming in as a hex encoded string. Probably need to parse that into a string to load the image.